# Plotting same equation but different graph. l

Tags: r, plot, graph, operator-keyword, taylor-series

I tried to plot Taylor expansion with the exponential function, f(x) = exp( x ) at a = 0 and by n = 1.

At first, I wrote the equation `#### n = 1` and plotted it. But It failed to fit the line to graph of `Exp(x)`. And I tried to relocate sign '+' to upper line, as see the equation `# n = 1`, and it worked.

These Equations are exactly same, except location of the operator sign ( + ).

What is difference between the equations ( `#### n = 1`, `# n = 1` ) for plotting?

Is it important the location of operator signs in plotting?

```
f1 <- function(x) exp( x )
x <- seq( -1, 1, by = 0.025 )


a <- 0

#### n = 1
f1.10 <- function( x ){
  exp( a ) / factorial( 0 ) * ( x - a )^0 
  + exp( a ) / factorial( 1 ) * ( x - a )^1
}


# n = 1
f1.1 <- function( x ){
  exp( a ) / factorial( 0 ) * ( x - a )^0 +
    exp( a ) / factorial( 1 ) * ( x - a )^1
}



plot( x, exp(x), ylab = "exp(x)", type = "l", lwd = 3 )
curve( f1.1, -0.5, 0.5, add = T, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "yellow" )
curve( f1.10, -0.5, 0.5, add = T, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = "blue" )
```

[image: [sample_output]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DjDp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R, `+` of line head means new line. If you put `+` at end of line, R recognize the next line in script as continuation of current line.
So,

```
f1.10 <- function( x ){
  exp( a ) / factorial( 0 ) * ( x - a )^0 
  + exp( a ) / factorial( 1 ) * ( x - a )^1
}
```

is the same as

```
f1.11 <- function( x ){
  exp( a ) / factorial( 1 ) * ( x - a )^1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two functions produce different results, and they're not the same.

```r
f1.10(seq(10))
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
f1.1(seq(10))
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

When n is `1` `f1.10` produce `1` and `f1.1` produce 2 or we can even produce a random number between `-0.5` and `0.5` as follows to see if they produce the same result.

```r
set.seed(777)
x <- runif(100, min = -0.5, max = 0.5)
min(f1.10(x))
#[1] -0.4940781
max(f1.10(x))
#[1] 0.4950499
min(f1.1(x))
#[1] 0.5059219
max(f1.1(x))
#[1] 1.49505
```

You can see that `f1.10` is constrained between `-0.5` and `0.5` where as `f1.1` is not.